# junit TEST_ID doesn't change every time i run junit

Tags: junit4

i am begineer in JUnit and has this issue can anyone please help me here.

Whenever i run JUnit the TEST_ID remains same and the values also.

for example:

****************TEST_ID_3****

a2
b3

Here no matter how many times i run JUnit for this class the TEST_ID is TEST_ID_3.
In this test case have called a method in which these values should increment and value of b3 should be one greater than a2. but the values also remain the same every time.

Can anyone help please.

Thank you  in advance

Comment: please include a [mcve] to your question.  we cannot tell you what's wrong with your code if you don't show us what you have done :/

Comment: You probably generate the ID using some non-persistent, non-changing, algorithm (or just have it hard coded).

Comment: Method for which the JUnit written is
public void addNewParticipant() {
  Participant participantObj = new Participant();
  p_List.add(participantObj);
 }
and the JUnit i wrote for the same is as follows and here values of "a" and "b" do not change they remain 2 and 3 every time i run the JUnit.
@Test
 public void addNewParticipant() {
  int a=AddMember.p_List().size();
  AddMember.addNewParticipant();
  int b=AddMember.p_List().size();
  SOP("a"+a);
  SOP("b"+b);
  AddMember.addNewParticipant(); 
  SOP("try "+ AddMember.p_List().size());
  }

Comment: @AJ_user7865516 it is really hard to read code in comments. Just update your question and append the code there.